# why can i not create a home page in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I was trying to create a new home page.
why do i get the following error "DL is deprecated, please use fiddle...could not find generator controllers"  i've tried to locate the following code in readline.rb file but cannot find it

```
if RUBY_VERSION < '1.9.1'      
 require 'Win32API'    
 else      
 require 'dl'       
class Win32API        
 DLL = {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question has very little detail, so it's not clear at all what you're using, I'm guessing you're on Windows, and I googled your error and it came up with a bunch of vagrant links so I'm guessing you're using vagrant.  [There's this issue](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/2656) and although it's closed, the author's comments suggest that he's still working on a fix.

#### Update

Sorry, I just noticed that the owner says [it's fixed for the next installers](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/2656#issuecomment-36203512).

Comment: Updated my answer, the owner does actually say it's fixed in the latest versions.